# How to display Index view in Pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a pdf document for displaying all information about any student. I am working with such a application where i am generating student's resume  in pdf format as per his\her details.

Comment: There are dozens of html to pdf questions here. Use the search function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: Thanks Verkion... but still i am not getting idea to create a dynamic pdf from view(cshtml file) in MVC 3.

Comment: @SonamMohite maybe [this](http://am22tech.com/s/22/Blogs/post/2011/09/28/HTML-To-PDF-using-iTextSharp.aspx) will point you in the right direction even though it's webforms.